# How to configure log4net for mySQL?

Tags: mysql, log4net

I am trying to log events in a mySQL database using a log4net appender but I do not manage to configure log4net file correctly,

Here is the log4net.config:

```
<appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1"/>
  <lossy value="false"/>
  <connectionType value="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
  <!--connectionString value="Server=my_server_ip_or_name;Database=my_db_name; Uid=my_user_name;Pwd=my_passwd;"/-->
  <connectionString value="server=my_server_ip_or_name;database=my_db_name; user=my_user_name;password=my_passwd;port=3306"/>
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log (dtLog,lbThread,lbLevel,lbLogger,lbMessage,lbException,lbContext) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @context)"/>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
    <dbType value="DateTime"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="32"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%t"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="10"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%p"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@context"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="10"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%x"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="512"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%c"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%m"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
  </parameter>

</appender>
```

At runtime, I get the following exception:

```
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\Config\\machine.config line 295)"}
```

Which corresponds to the following config line:

```
<add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
```

The debug of log4net logs the following error:

> iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Authentication to host 'my_server_ip_or_name' for user 'my_user_name' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'my_user_name'@'my_local_machine_name' (using password: YES)
>
> log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Could not open database connection [server=my_server_ip_or_name;database=my_db_name; user=my_user_name;password=my_passwd;port=3306]. Connection string context [ConnectionString].
>       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication to host 'my_server_ip_or_name' for user 'my_usr_name' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'my_user_name'@'my_local_machine_name' (using password: YES) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'my_user_name'@'my_local_machine_name' (using password: YES)

I do not understand why log4net tries to connect to my local computer instead of the server I configured.

Any idea of what is wrong in my config?

Comment: Can the down votes explain their reason, thanks

Comment: does your mysql user have the rights to connect from the ip address you're trying to connect from?

Comment: Tip for the future: explicitly mention that you anonymised the configuration data especially when your question is about said configuration. If you don't then the first assumption people must make is that you bluntly copy/pasted stuff from a guide and simply didn't know you needed to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TZHX noticed, I had to grant remote access for the mySQL user at the remote IP:

```
GRANT ALL ON my_db_name.* TO my_user_name@'my_remote_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_passwd';
```

I also had to comment the MySql sitemap config in the machine.config file:

```
<!--add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" /-->
```